# What does defvar do in this code?

Tags: variables, defvar

I know this may sound silly but what does `defvar` do in the code below? Does it define a variable that hold a capture template? or we say that the template is bound to the variable `capture-template-contact`?

I tried `C-h f defvar` for help but still don't get it being a non-native speaker of English.

```
   (defvar my/capture-template-contact
      (concat "* %^{Name}\n"
              ":PROPERTIES:\n"
              ":Created: %U\n"
              ":Birthday: yyyy-mm-dd\n"
              ":Email:\n"
              ":Mobile:\n"
              ":Skype:\n"
              ":Address:\n"
              ":City:\n"
              ":State:\n"
              ":Country:\n"
              ":PostalCode:\n"
              ":Website:\n"
              ":Note:\n"
              ":END:\n") "Contact")
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Removed the extraneous code after the `defvar` expression.

Comment: maybe it is defining a format string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `defvar` declares a global variable, more precisely, a variable that is dynamically bound. And it can define that variable, that is, give it an initial value.
2. If only one value (the variable symbol) is passed to `defvar` then it does not give the variable a value; it just declares it.
3. `defvar` does nothing if the variable it defines already has a value.

> Does it define a variable that hold a capture template? or we say that the template is bound to the variable capture-template-contact?

It defines a variable `my/capture-template-contact` if that's not already defined. It gives it the string value that's the result of that `(concat ...)` expression. It gives the variable the doc string `"Contact"`. That's all it does. As for your second question, the `defvar` doesn't answer that question - it says nothing about what the variable it defines means, or how it might be used in some code somewhere. And the variable name is `my/capture-template-contact`, not `capture-template-contact`.

The Elisp manual, node [Defining Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html), tells you what you need to know about `defvar`.

Comment: Thank you. I moved all my capture templates in such variables. 
If you were to write a git log message how would you caption such a change? `Use variables for each capture template` or `Define variables to hold capture templates`?

Comment: That's up to you; I have no advice about that. I'd imagine that you're the one who most needs to understand what your message means.

Comment: Why have you chosen not to customize `org-capture-templates`?